# What is the best worst possible runtime for generic list sorting algorithm and how do we know this?

Tags: algorithm, sorting, big-o

If we cannot make any special assumptions about the nature of the elements of a passed linked list to a function that sorts the linked list (only that they are compared), what is the best possible worst case runtime for this sorting algorithm? How do we know and what is the limiting consideration here?

Algorithm:
[image: List sorting algorithm]

Comment: How is returning the two first values relevant? Or is this to suggest that the sorting algorithm does not really have to sort everything, but only place the two smallest nodes at the front? You mention *"this sorting algorithm"*: what does this refer to? `sort` is not further detailed...

Comment: What algorithm is doing the sorting? That determines the complexity.